# Deleting blank rows and rows with text in them at the same time

Tags: python, csv, rows

New to programming here. After going through google and the forums (aswell as much trial and error), I couldn't find a neat solution to my problem.

I'd like to delete a few initial rows (first 10 rows) in my spreadsheet/CSV file and while I did find the solution to that using:

```
    all(next(read) for i in range(10))
```

It does not appear to be able to delete the blank rows in the CSV file that I have. The first 10 rows I'd like to delete include those blank rows. I think the above line only deletes the rows if there are strings in them.

My full code is this so far [EDIT1]: Maybe this could work?

```
    import csv
    with open('filename.csv') as csvfile:
       non_blank_row=[]
       filecsv = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
       for row in filecsv:
              non_blank_row.append(row)

       better_blank_row = non_blank_row[[i for i in range(len(non_blank_row)) if non_blank_row!=[]
```

[EDIT2]: When I tried to print(better_blank_row), I did:

```
    for i in better_blank_row:
        print(better_blank_row)
```

However, I'm not sure why output doesn't come out.. like the shell just freezes.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is just iterating over *filecsv*. It's not doing anything.
You want something like

`non_blank_rows = []
 for row in filecsv:
    if row: # empty strings are false-y
       non_blank_rows.append(row)`

Now at this point you could just set filecsv to be non_blank_rows. 
Note that the more pythonic way to do all of this would probably be to use a list comprehension. I'd write the syntax for that, but if that's something you haven't heard about you might want to look them up on your own.

`filecsv = [row for row in filecsv if row]`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I was wondering if this would be better:
with open('filename.csv') as csvfile
        non_blank_rows=[]
        filecsv = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
        for row in filecsv:
                 non_blank_rows.append(row)
        
        Then to delete the blank rows perhaps:
        better_rows=non_blank_rows[[i for i in range(len(non_blank_row) if non_blank_row[i]!=[] or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

you can use as fallowing for writing new csv file after deleting particuler row's

```
import csv
#read csv file
csvfile =  open('/home/17082016_ExpiryReport.csv', 'rb')
filecsv = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")

#following line increment pointer for blank line also up to range 10 lines  
[next(filecsv) for i in range(10)]

#write csv file
with open('/home/17082016_ExpiryReport_output.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    [csvwriter.writerow(i) for i in filecsv ]
```